# Ideal split for Kitchen and Living room on across five circuits

Tags: electrical, kitchens

So I've started renovating my 18' x 13' kitchen/dining area, and thanks to an old sagging ceiling that's getting ripped out, I have the opportunity to redo electric in not only that room but the adjacent living room.  There are a total of five 20a circuits serving these two rooms currently broken down as follows:

1. Outlets in kitchen area (including stove), all
   outlets in living room + exterior outlet in driveway
2. Overhead lights in kitchen, dining area, living room, + porch light
3. Refrigerator + outlets in dining area
4. Dishwasher by itself
5. Garbage disposal by itself

All appliances including garbage disposal were purchased in 2015 and are energy star rated.  The living room has a new 55" HDTV, older sony stereo, and quite a bit of computer gear.  All lights fixtures are LEDs and never pull more than 1a.

Seems like it would make a lot of sense to have the living room outlets on their own circuits, but not sure which one I should steal to do this.

- Is there a code reason that overhead lights must be on their own circuit?
- Does it make sense to have the GD and DW on their own circuits?
- What about the exterior porch light and driveway outlet?

Wiring is 12 awg.  Located in California.  My city just follows state building codes.

Comment: How many watts does the dishwasher pull, and how many HP is the disposal?

Comment: Having trouble finding specs for the dishwasher but it's the standard Whirpool $500 one with an average energy state rating.  The guide does say a dedicated circuit is recommended but not required.  The disposal is an ISE 3/4th HP.

Comment: Can you find the nameplate label on the dishwasher itself? (Look around the inside of the door, or somewhere else inside the dishwasher)

Comment: Do you have physical access between the renovation area and the service panel to potentially add circuits?

Comment: Yes, the service panel is behind one of the kitchen walls, so as I complete the demo I'll soon have access to everything around the panel

Comment: Dishwasher label says "motor 1.2 amp total 8.1 amp, 120V"

Comment: Code requires 2 20 amp small appliance circuits, when I have limited circuits I will usually put the fridge, garbage disposal and dish dishwasher on one circuit and make sure not to use the disposal at the same time as the dishwashers is running, the dining area will also require a 20 amp circuit   Your plan with the fridge and dining room will work fine , then all the lighting including the porch And outside outlet  can be on another circuit.

Comment: How many open spaces do you have in your panel? What make and model is it, for that matter?

Comment: Panel is full.  It's an older Sylvania, 125 amp max with a 100a main breaker.

Comment: @JohnHeyer can you post photos of the panel then? That'd help us determine the full scope of work here